# python write error

Tags: python, join, for-loop, overwrite

```
def save_friend(filename, friends_list):
    rows = ''
    strings = open(filename, 'Ur')
    for c in strings:
        rows += ','.join(c)
        rows += '\n'


    return strings.write(rows)
```

trying to overwrite a list `(friends_list)` to a file `(filename)`. Keep getting this error 
message when testing `IOError: File not open for writing`. But my previous function opens files just fine..

Comment: trying using 'w+' instead of 'Ur'

Comment: w+ will allow him to write to the file, but as he hasn't set strings to anything it will create an empty file.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the mode `'w'` if you want to open the file for writing. Since you are already using '\n' as newline, you can get rid of the `'U'` mode.